# Php замена последней буквы

Tags: php, замена

Помогите с заменом последней буквы в зависимости от буквы.Тоесть есть имя Рома увидел букву а и поменял на е,или к примеру ещё Роман тоесть конец согласный и добавляет букву у с результатом Роману

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот то, что вам нужно:
http://morpher.ru/php/
http://namecaselib.com/ru/